# memory leak using MBProgressHUD

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management

I am using the MBProgressHUB, with variations on the code found [here](http://snipplr.com/view/26643/mbprogresshud-with-an-asynchronous-nsurlconnection-call/).

Some things about my code:

- The code is in my App Delegate
- A number of other classes call it
- I'm using it with asynchronous NSURLConnection
- I do *not* declare it: @property (nonatomic, retain) MBProgressHUD *HUD;
- I do *not*: @synthesize HUD;
- (and of course I do not release it in my dealloc)

I use it as follows:

```
- (void)setSearchingMode:(BOOL)isSearching {
    // when network action, toggle network indicator and activity indicator
    if (isSearching) {
        [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
        
        UIWindow *theWindow = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
        HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithWindow:theWindow];
        [theWindow addSubview:HUD];
        
        //HUD.labelText = @"Connecting";
        [HUD show:YES];
    } else {
        [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
        
        [HUD hide:YES];
        [HUD removeFromSuperview];
        [HUD release];
    }
}

- (void)setSearchingText:(NSString *)whatToSay {
    HUD.labelText = whatToSay;
}
```

I am fairly sure that the code is causing a memory management problem somewhere. In my crash log, I get:

> Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
> Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x0000000c
>
> 0   libobjc.A.dylib   0x000027d8 objc_msgSend + 16
> 1   My            0x00003120 -[MyAppDelegate setSearchingMode:] (MyAppDelegate.m:363)
> 2   My            0x00003458 -[MyAppDelegate connectionDidFinishLoading:] (MyAppDelegate.m:341)
> 3   Foundation        0x00032896 -[NSURLConnection(NSURLConnectionReallyInternal) sendDidFinishLoading] + 62
> 4   Foundation        0x00032818 _NSURLConnectionDidFinishLoading + 72

in connectionDidFinishLoading I call:

```
[self setSearchingMode:NO];
```

I tried to do it by making property accessors for HUD, but was not able to get around the line "[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithWindow" - and I don't want to keep on alloc'ing an ivar!

Thanks, if anyone can point me in a better direction here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you happen to end up with the sequence of:

```
[self setSearchingMode:YES];
[self setSearchingMode:NO];
[self setSearchingMode:NO];
```

That code will crash as described because of the dangling reference to `HUD`.  When you do `[HUD release];`, add `HUD = nil;` after that line.

It isn't a memory leak;  it is an over-release.  Or, more likely, a dangling reference.

> (and of course I do not release it in
>   my dealloc)

Why not? If you retain it, you better release it!

Comment: I'm fairly certain I don't do as you suggest, since the only calls to setSearchingMode:NO are when a) if I don't get a connection with NSURLConnection, b) didFailWithError from the locationManager, c) didFailWithError from NSURLConnection, and d) connectionDidFinishLoading. Still, what if somehow I am? Will adding HUD = nil; stop it from being over-released? And I don't release it in dealloc since I release it in my function setSearchingMode:NO

Comment: setting the variable to `nil` after releasing it will prevent `release` messages from being sent to garbage memory (and thus causing an `exc_bad_access` crash). Messages sent to nil don't do anything, the message is effectively discarded, but messages sent to a deallocated object (memory that is pointed to by a variable that used to point to a valid object) will cause crashes, because the memory now being pointed at is no longer valid. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Hey, that's new to me! If I allocate memory for an object, then release it, and release it again, I will have memory management problems. But if I allocate memory for an object, release it, then set it to nil, then I could release it again without memory management problems?