# Getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS when loading view (MBProgressHUD+ASIHTTPRequest)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, asihttprequest

Greetz,

I am currently having issues managing a "Loading" screen on my mainViewController (The first view the user accesses.) So basically the first view downloads an image and puts it on a UIImageView. While this happens the MBProgressHUD is displayed. Now then, the user goes to a secondView with its own controller. The user uploads an image and goes back. When the user goes back to the mainView, the mainView gets reloaded so the same image as before is NOT displayed. So logically, the "Loading" MBProgressHUD should display aswell. Nonetheless it crashes before it can even let it display, it crashes while making the transition.

The thing is the error exc_bad_access comes only if I have the MBProgressHUD implemented (must be a problem with memory management but I don't seem to get it...) These are the segments with the code in question:

mainViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {   
   HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view];
   [self.view addSubview:HUD];
   HUD.delegate = self;
   HUD.labelText = @"Please Wait";
   [HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(loadingOfImageAndInformation) onTarget:self        withObject:nil animated:YES];
   [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void) loadingOfImageAndInformation {
    // [...] get URL and blabla.
    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:imageURL];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestLoadDone:)];
    [request setDidFailSelector:@selector(requestLoadWentWrong:)];
    [request setDownloadProgressDelegate:HUD];
    [request startAsynchronous];
}

- (void)hudWasHidden {
   // Remove HUD from screen when the HUD was hidded
   [HUD removeFromSuperview];
   [HUD release];
   // HUD = nil; I tried this because I found it on another 
   // answer in S.O. but it didn't quite work. 
   // I don't think it is the same case.
   // I also tried putting this on the dealloc method and 
   // the didReceiveMemoryWarning to no avail... 
}
```

This is the other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4494260/memory-leak-using-mbprogresshud) that treats a similar problem but that didn't really solve mine.

Thank you very much for your future help!!

Comment: If you need the build stack let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set `HUD` as the downloadProgressDelegate of `request`.  Perhaps `request` tries to send a message to it after you release `HUD`.  If you run your code in the debugger, the stack trace you get on the crash should tell you if this is the case.

Comment: I released the HUD at the hudWasHidden method. Just for code cleanliness that should be correct. However I considered what you said and just commented out the releasing of the HUD. And now it works but it should not! I don't get it. If the view is reloaded shouldn't it create a new HUD when the view is Loaded? And not try to use the first instance of it? I would appreciate if you could explain...

Comment: @Joze: Did you try setting the downloadProgressDelegate to nil just before releasing HUD?

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry but I haven't read the entire question. Usually when you get EXC_BAD_ACCESS it will be pretty easy to figure out if you enable NSZombie. If it doesn't help drop a comment and I'll see if I can improve my answer.

To activate NSZombie do the following:

1. Get info of the executable.
2. Go to the arguments tab.
3. In the "Variables to be set in the environment:" section add:

Name: NSZombieEnabled
Value: YES

Then run your app as usual and when it crashes it should tell you which deallocated object received the release message.